# How to make a UIBarButtonItem NOT scaleToFit?

Tags: uibutton, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I'm creating a UIBarButtonItem with a custom image:

```
UIButton *tempSpeedButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
        UIImage *speedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"eye"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [tempSpeedButton setBackgroundImage:speedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [tempSpeedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onSpeed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        tempSpeedButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        UIBarButtonItem* speedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempSpeedButton];
```

The image appears stretched out. How can I make it fit normally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add this:

[tempSpeedButton sizeToFit];